# Mobile data limiter keeps enabling itself

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, data-monitoring, motorola-droid-razr

I'm 'grandfathered' in on Verizon's old 'unlimited' data program so I'm trying to get the data limiter to be completely disabled (or removed if that's possible).

Going to system->data usage->and unticking 'set mobile data limit' works to disable the mobile limits for a few days but after a while it re-enables itself and I get the 'mobile data limit exceeded' notification. Setting the data limit to some ungodly amount (terabytes) doesn't seem to have any effect.

The phone is a Razr Maxx with stock ICS 4.0.4. Not rooted currently but if that would help in solving the issue I have no problem making it happen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Try checking the limit box and then setting limit and warning bars higher some other forums have said it should work